# run method of another class with parameter in separate thread

Tags: c#, wpf

```
using System;

public class ImageConverter
{
    public void button1_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       string filename=null;
       SendImageToPlayer send = new SendImageToPlayer();
       //send.ReadImageFile(filename);
       Thread t = new Thread(new send.ReadImageFile);
       uint ret=send.ErrorCode;
    }
}

public class SendImageToPlayer
{
    ...
    public void ReadImageFile(string PfileName)
    {
       //something
    }
    ...
}
```

The code above shown will not work. I want to run ReadImageFie in separate thread. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a property `FileName` on your SendImageToPlayer class and set it before you start the thread.

```
using System;

public class ImageConverter
{
    public void button1_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      string filename = "c:\myfile.bmp";
      SendImageToPlayer send = new SendImageToPlayer();
      send.Filename = filename;
      Thread t = new Thread(send.ReadImageFile);
      t.Start();
}
```

Consider using the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) thread class.  It provides events when the thread completes.

You check the ErrorCode when the [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event is fired.

Answer (score 2):

You should start your thread after creating it: `t.Start()` ;

You should also consider using the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) instead.

Oh, oh, I just noticed you want to pass a parameter. You can set a property in your `SendImageToPlayer` instance prior to starting the thread, or pass an `object` to the `ReadImagefile` function. But really, use the TPL, it's better.